# how to properly integrate kalman filter in a project?

Tags: control-system, kalman-filter

this can be a little bit complex to understand, so I ll try my best to explain and hopefully someone can answer me or guide me on this.

I'm doing a time series prediction on some data that I have, the project is to predict the vehicle trajectory. my data set consists of 40k data points and I have 5 features which are longitudinal and lateral Acceleration, speed, yaw rate, wheel angle and timestamp so my project is about predicting the position from those features except timestamp of course because it doesn't count as a feature.

so what I first thought about was to use Neural Networks and yes maybe it was a bad decision to start with. I had bad results and the network was not able to converge or rather to generalize, I tried FFNN and RNN/LSTM too since I'm doing a time series predictions but as I said the results was bad maybe because my data are not informative enough or the quality of my data are bad etc.. since I'm sure that there was no problem in the model itself or some hyper parameter choice or something.

I read recently that for this type of problems, peoples or engineers use the Kalman Filter. Now the first what I though about was how can I integrate a kalman filter algorithm in my project? I made some search how the kalman filter work but I didn't know where to start. I mean for Neural Network the process would be to build a model by letting it train on the data and then save it as a .pkl or .pt(pytorch) file or something and after deploy I ll just call prediction on the new data with that model and receive the results. My question is how would this deploying process look like with the Kalman Filter, I don't want to start something if I knew that in the end I ll not be able to use it or rather integrate it in my project.

It seems like I don't have to build a model and deploy it when using kalman filter. so how can I use those 40k data points that I have with kalman filter and then test the results?

I'm using python as a programming language

Comment: You can't use Kalman if you don't understand it. It's not a plug-and-play for the ignorant. You'll need to develop a state space model and probably need to do some diffeq to get there. Then you loop continually over: (1) predict new state based on old state, which increases uncertainty; then, (2) update estimate from measurements, which decreases uncertainty. But you really need to know what you are doing. It looses its advantages if you don't have any a priori knowledge. It is absolutely necessary to first understand the system being estimated.

Comment: @jonk thnx, in my case I don't have a mathematical model if that is what you mean. I can't model my system mathematically and derive a transfer function for example. The only thing I have is the dataset which consists of the features that I described above and other than that I only know that my system is a vehicle. that's all so do I need the equations of vehicle dynamics, is that what you mean? and does different vehicles will behave the same? I just don't know where to start I have only the dataset and the knowledge that my system is a vehicle

Comment: Say you have various sensors used to maintain an estimate of the relative position of another aircraft ahead of yours. You know, a priori, that aircraft cannot turn around instantly, etc. There's a LOT of things they cannot do. There are also a lot of things they can do. The more you know about those limitations, the better. You sensors their own other limitations, position errors, rate errors, acceleration errors, noise, and gosh knows what else. You need a priori info about each sensor and target in order to reject the impossible, etc. Modeling the dynamics is part of the problem.

Comment: Since your system is a vehicle, here's what you do: (1) work out all you can to provide simulation equations for the drive system and motion capabilities; (2) simulate them using a Kalman filter observer with arbitrary noise and loop back to (1) above it it works poorly; (3) incorporate actual noise information from your sensor datasheets and test again; (4) make empirical measurements from the actual sensors and check against datasheets; (5) repeat for all of the sensors you want to consider; (6) begin developing embedded software for trials. Something like that. It is real work. Not play.

Comment: Otherwise, don't use Kalman. Just find a different approach. If you must use a "one size fits all" algorithm, then Kalman is **NOT** the algorithm of choice. There are lots of other simple methods based upon very prosaic assumptions (for example, just average/decimate your data, blindly) which are fast and difficult to get wrong. They may, or may not, work well. (If you want to process complex, multi-sensor data and fuse it well to a single estimation, as when flying a quadcopter, then Kalman is the only way to go.) But simple algorithms can do reasonable things, too. So go with what you know.

Comment: The Kalman filter has turned into this popular notion of "the filter that does everything", but "Kalman" does not mean "magic" in Hungarian.  It's actually the name of a region where some Hungarians (including Rudi Kalman) come from.  A Kalman filter is a filter that has been designed with *a specific methodology*, and that methodology *won't make any sense to you* until you understand multivariate differential equations and multivariate statistics.  It's not something you can design by knowing the names of the files that you feed to some mysterious piece of code.

Comment: You might have enough information in that dataset to determine a sufficient vehicle model to then use a Kalman filter.  Basically you'd have to develop a parameterized vehicle dynamic model and then use your dataset to determine the parameters.  However, unless there are unrealistic constraints on your vehicle dynamics (namely the constraint that the tires don't slip) then you probably can't do more than to roughly determine how much the position and orientation have *changed* over various time intervals.